# How does galactic war determine difficulty?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

How does the Galactic War determine the difficulty of your next battles? Is it based on your arena rating, player level, character levels? Random?

I will fight a few battles against level 30's, then hit a battle with level 46's. Then the levels drop back down again.

I am currently level 44. But it has been doing this the past few battles.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A community manager for the game [addressed this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/SWGalaxyOfHeroes/comments/469vj1/sad_post_i_was_wrong_about_galactic_war_using/) on the unofficial subreddit.  It turns out to be mainly based on your highest Squad Power from a PvP win (whether in GW or Arenas) and not on Arena Rank:

> **INRAJ:** "Arena Rank, why do we save their highest rank and then pick opponents against it?"
>   **ASD:** "We don't. We decided not to use that method a while ago."
>   **INRAJ:** "Wait. What?"
>   **ASD:** "Yeah, we don't do that anymore. We just use their highest Squad Power now."
>
> [...]
>
> We use your **LAST PVP SQUAD WIN** so long as that power is greater than the last time you won. So we DO take it from Arena, just not RANK, just Squad Power.

As well, your general experience [is factored in](https://www.reddit.com/r/SWGalaxyOfHeroes/comments/40zdlw/psa_retreating_in_galactic_war_will_now_reset/cyzf7dx):

> When new players join the game, they're assigned to a new bucket so they're grouped with other new players. We don't put new players in to a bucket where everyone is already 60--THAT would be unfair.

Enemies also get harder the further you progress in the war:

> Galactic War is designed to have stronger opponents at the end, and to encourage the player to get stronger.

Comment: I've only unlocked galactic war 4 or 5 days ago. But so far, I've yet to have a character killed. Most fights, I just put it on auto. So, I'm assuming I'm still in the "new bucket" then? Because it is stupidly easy right now. Usually, I out-level the opposing team by 10 or more levels per character.

Comment: @Ellesedil Sounds like it.  What level are you?  I found it got harder in the low-mid 50s, since I ended up facing mainly 60-65s.  I'm now 61 with higher-* characters and it's easier again, facing teams from 48 to 68.

Comment: I'm level 42 with level 41 characters. I regularly come up against teams in the low 30's. With some strong support characters and 2.5 healers (Ahsoka is half a healer, sort of). it's pretty difficult for a character to die on my team.

Answer (score 0):

Was supposed to be a comment, but grew too large:

Don t have any other source than my own experience, but it seems to be linked to your Arena rank.

The game inform you the team you are facing are real player team, so it would be logical to take player rank into account for difficulty.

Furthermore, I usually do Arena battle after completing Galactic War, and always end them. The only time the enemy was too powerful for me was when I ranked up in arena before facing GW.

TL:DR: without any source nor enought hard data, I would say from personal experience it is linked to your Arena Rank.

Comment: Do you know if it determines your opponents with your current rank at each battle or when you click reset?

Comment: I think it determine whenever it load the next opponent, so when you click reset and when you finish a fight.

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest version update (22/11/2017), GW is now capped at the difficulty a new player who has just reached level 85 would receive.

Once you're level 85, regardless of how powerful your own squads become, GW will have the same difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who has responded is incorrect. I win using 2 characters, and even though my GP is quite high and my best two squads are over 100,000, my final battles are up against squads that I can beat without even looking at the screen. Here is how:

Whittle down the GP by using your best squad to kill off a few. Lose on purpose in the final battle to win with a weaker squad. Over time, the GP of all battles will lower. I have won a few hundred on auto and set my last squad at something lower each time.

After I add another Zeta to my Revan or Darth Revan, I will solo the final battle with them. Then I'll start using something like Yoda+Anakin, etc., to keep lowering the Galactic War difficulty.

[image]
[image]
[image]